# What is wrong with my css media query?

Tags: html, css

I'm playing around with some basic media queries. I'm not sure what is wrong but the image doesn't show up in the div (id="image"), no matter what I do with it. I am currently only testing this on Chrome and other desktop browsers. Thanks in advance for your feedback!

I have a div with the following CSS:

html:

```
<div id="image"></div>
```

css:

```
#image {
    background: url(300x250_A.jpg); 
}

@media screen and (min-width:300px) {
    #image { 
        background: url(300x250_A.jpg); 
    }
}
```

Comment: The image is in the same folder as the CSS file? Can you see the image in resolutions less than 300 pixels?

Comment: Does this `300x250_A.jpg` file exist?

Comment: give `#image` a height: `#image { height: 250px; width: auto; }`

Comment: did you check the path location....

Comment: You don't see anything, because your `div` is collapsed. Set some `height` to it, and you will see the background.

Comment: none of the two css declarations work?? the first one and that inside the media query?? none of these two work??

Comment: well this is not related to media query as media query portion is working but issue was with height of image..

Comment: Quotes around the url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply give #image a height:

```
#image { 
    height: 250px; 
    width: auto;
    background: url('300x250_A.jpg');
}
```

This can seem confusing, but think about it like this: as your `#image` is empty it has no dimensions, even though you gave it a background via css.

Just for good measure, it is nice to wrap the path to your image inside single quotes `#image { background: url('path/to/image.jpg') ... }`

Answer (score 3):

You need to give your `div` dimensions or add some content (a `&nbsp;` as space will be sufficient). Otherwise your div will not be rendered.

```
<div id="image">
    &nbsp;
</div>
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Loxos/gqrjrqgm/) as example.

Answer (score 1):

Your `<div>` is currently empty. You need to set the `height` in order to show up. See the difference between with height and without height.

```css
.with-height {height: 100px;}

#image { 
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/640/480/); 
}

@media screen and (min-width:300px) {
  #image { 
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/640/480/); 
  }
}
```

```html
Can you see the image below?
<div id="image"></div>
Can you see the image above?

<hr />

Can you see the image below?
<div id="image" class="with-height"></div>
Can you see the image above?
```

**Preview**

[image]

Comment: There is currently no CSS file. It's all in one page, so the HTML page and the images are in the same folder.

By the way, this is my first post here in Stack Overflow. Amazing community!

Comment: @SupremeNoob Use `&nbsp;` inside the `<div>` or add inline style like `style="height: 100px;"`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this

```
@media (min-width: 300px) {
#page {
background: url('nextpage.png') repeat-x;
}}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
#page { background: url('nextpage2.png') repeat-x;
}
}
```